# Where does Travis CI put my source files?

Tags: git, docker, travis-ci

My project requires various tools to build. I have put these tools into a Docker container and pushed it to DockerHub.

Now I would like to configure Travis CI to build my GitHub project using this Docker image.

What I have:

- The name and release of an image on DockerHub
- A bash script that builds my project (using the tools in the Docker image)
- A public Git repo

What I want to achieve:

- A "Build Passing" badge for `master` branch on GitHub
- Build results of the resulting `git pull` for PRs on GitHub

What should my `.travis.yml` file look like to achieve this?

Comment: What sequence of commands do you use locally to build your code on a docker container?

Comment: I can run `master` on Docker using `git clone` and `make`, but I want to test the PR, not `master`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount the clone/checkout of your PR that travis does for you as a volume into the docker container and then operate on that.

```
script: 
  - docker run -v ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}:/root/src/ ${IMAGE} /root/src/some_script.sh
```

where some_script.sh in your repo runs whatever (test) steps you like. If you configure the travis build to also build PR (via the web frontend) this automagically does the right thing for the PR builds as well as branch pushes.

[complete example yml](https://github.com/dune-community/dune-gdt/blob/master/.travis.yml#L25)